# Get time format in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timezone, utc-time

If I want get Ubuntu system time, I have two options:

```
$ cat /etc/timezone
US/Eastern

$ date
Sun Sep 15 14:45:02 EDT 2013
```

How can I find out if PostgreSQL is using utc or a utc offset, such as US/Eastern?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`current_setting()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-admin.html) function to get the `TIMEZONE` setting.

```
SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE') TZ;
```

Sample output:

```
# SELECT  current_setting('TIMEZONE') TZ;
     tz     
------------
 US/Eastern
(1 row)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/1696)** demo

Answer (score 1):

To see all relevant settings for local time (and some irrelevant, too), you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings
WHERE name ~* 'time'
```

In particular, the settings for `TimeZone` and `lc_time` should be of interest to you. (The time zone is not the only relevant detail for `time format`.) You get a short description in the column `short_desc`.) [More details for these settings in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT)

If you are only interested in one particular setting, the shortest form is:

```
SHOW timezone;
```

Returns the same as `SELECT current_setting('timezone')` (like [peterm provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49921/3684)), but the latter can also be integrated into DML SQL queries.